# How to calculate the ratio between DPI and MB in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, print-composer, dpi

I need to make maps that do not exceed a limit of 20 MB.
Up until now I worked with DPI values, that I choose when I export maps from the print composer
[image]

Maps with the same DPI have a different  MB of, a fact that I think is link to the complexity of the project. As an example a map with a HD raster will be with higher MB relatively to a similar map without the raster, both maps with the same DPI.
My question is: Can I choose the MB of the export image like the DPI?

Comment: No, as I wrote it is an image (JPEG/PNG) and not PDF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to precisely calculate the exported file size for some non-compressed formats (e.g. TIF without any compression, BMP, etc.; this is a handy [file-size calculator](http://jan.ucc.nau.edu/lrm22/pixels2bytes/calculator.htm)). It depends on dimensions and color depth. Some header information might slightly increase the total file size.

**However**, to keep file size smaller, it is good to wisely use some *compression* (in case of loss-less some one prefers to say *compaction*). You can save a lot of disk space, but you cannot estimate precisely the the file size of the exported map. The results might vary o lot, depending on the map complexity, selected format and settings.